# How to fix cannot find symbol when I try to access an object made from another class in Java

Tags: java, class, object

Hi I'm still new to object oriented coding.
I have these two object made in different classes, when I try to compile it this error happens:
**AddressBook.java:20: error: cannot find symbol (at Entry)**

Is there anyway I can fix this?

```
public class Entry 
{
    public String name;
    public String email; 
    public String emailTwo;
    
    public Entry(String name, String email, String emailTwo){}
}
```

```
public class AddressBook
{
    private ArrayList<Entry> entry; //address book will be a list of all addressbooks, each one contains a name and an entry (which is also an object containing multiple entries) 
    
    private String addressName; 
    
    public AddressBook(String addressName, ArrayList<Entry> oldEntry) {}
}
```

Comment: Entry class is also provided by Java. I think you might have imported the wrong Entry class in your project. Can you please check once import of your classes or update the import in your question which can help to identify the problem faster.

Comment: @NaveenKumar I just have the usual java.util.* and java.io.* did I need to import my Entry class as well?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the import will be?

Comment: What is the package name where you have put your Entry class? For e.g. if it is under com.abc then you have to import com.abc.Entry in your class

Comment: Just for trial purpose, change the name of your Entry class to something else and then retry.